# HBASE versus HIVE: What is more suitable for data that is uniquely defined by multiple fields?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

We are building a DB infrastructure on the top of Hadoop systems. We will be paying a vendor to do that and I do not think we are getting the right answers from the first vendor. So, I need the help from some experts to validate if I am right or I miss something
1. We have about 1600 fields in the data. A unique record is identified by those 1600 records

2. We want to be able to search records in a particular timeframe
   (aka, records for a given time frame)
3. There are some fields that change overtime (monthly)

The vendor stated that the best way to go is HBASE and that they have to choices: (1) make the search optimize for machine learning (2) make adhoc queries.
 The (1) will require a concatenate key with all the fields of interest. The key length will determine how slow or fast the search will run.

I do not think this is correct. 
1. We do not need to use HBASE. We can use HIVE
2. We do not need to concatenate field names. We can translate those to a number and have a key as a number
3. I do not think we need to choose one or the other.

Could you let me know what you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what is your use case. In simpler terms, Hive alone is not good when it comes to `interactive` queries however one of the best when it comes to analytics.

Hbase on the other hand, is really good for interactive queries, however doing analytics would not be that easy as hive.

> We have about 1600 fields in the data. A unique record is identified by those 1600 records

**HBase**

Hbase is a NoSQL, columner database which stores information in Map(Dictionary) like format. Where each row needs to have one column which uniquely identifies the row.  This is called `key`.

You can have key as a combination of multiple columns as well if you don't have a single column which can uniquely identifies the row. And then you can search record using `partial key`. However this is going to affect the performance ( as compared to have single column key).

**Hive:**

Hive has a SQL like language (HQL) to Query HDFS, which you can use for analytics. However, it doesn't require any primary key so you can insert duplicate records if required.

> The vendor stated that the best way to go is HBASE and that they have
>   to choices: (1) make the search optimize for machine learning (2) make
>   adhoc queries. The (1) will require a concatenate key with all the
>   fields of interest. The key length will determine how slow or fast the
>   search will run.

In a way your vendor is correct, as I explained earlier.

> 1. We do not need to use HBASE. We can use HIVE 2. We do not need to concatenate field names. We can translate those to a number and have a key as a number 3. I do not think we need to choose one or the other.

Weather you can use **HBASE** or **Hive**  is depends on your use case. However, if you are planning to use Hive then you don't even need to generate a `pseudo key` (row numbers you are talking about)

There is one more option if you have hortonworks deployment. Consider `Hive` for analytics and `LLAP` for interactive queries.

Comment: Thanks Shah. So, your recommendation is basically "do not go with HBASE" but, use HIVE and LLAP in top of HIVE for interactive queries. Is that right?

Comment: I see that we can put HIVE in the top of HBASE. https://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-part-1/

Comment: Is this the way to go? Create the table in HBASE, then, use HIVE for the SQL like interactive queries

Comment: @user5987994 as I said, it all depends on your use case.  to which application are you trying to feed that ? Depends on the requirement of the application you can decide.